# C lang sizeof(char[]) get static size

Tags: c, arrays, char, sizeof

I want to get char array size but I cant do that

let see

```
#define MAX 64

char value[MAX]

value = "hi"    //or something initialization
sizeof("hi")    //result = 3
sizeof(value)   // result = 64
```

I want to get `sizeof("hi") == sizeof(value)`
How cant I do?

Comment: Does this even compile? I was unaware you could assign an array as you've done in line 5.

Comment: Oh, but you've got more syntax errors so this is just an example. Never mind.

Comment: `strlen(value) == 2`

Comment: Post real code (that at least compiles)

Comment: You can make `sizeof("hi") == sizeof(value)` if you make `"hi"` and `value` have the same size.

Comment: Please post real code instead of "or something"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet that you've included, you're actually setting the size of `value` to 64. As a result `sizeof(value)` will return 64 * `sizeof(char)`.
This is correct, regardless of what you're putting into the array `value`.

Perhaps what you're trying to do is to get the array to be automatically sized at compile time? e.g.

```
char value[] = "hi";
int value_size = sizeof(value); // value_size will now equal 3, as the array contains { 'h', 'i', '\0' }
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(value)`, with `char value[MAX]` returns the size of `char` multipled by`MAX`. Therefore, the length of the string stored in `value` will never be the size of `value`.